# Using Charles proxy with shared connection with no proxy server configuration

Tags: http, proxy, network-programming

I want to use Charles proxy on all traffic that comes from iOS devices connected to my shared network, without configuring any proxy server settings on devices.

I have created a shared ethernet connection over Wi-Fi on a Mac machine.
I have connected the devices I want to monitor to the shared Wi-Fi.

Charles proxy works fine, but I can only see requests from the Mac, and not from the devices connected to the shared Wi-Fi. If I add manual proxy config on devices, it works fine.

Is there a way to redirect all traffic that goes through the shared Wi-Fi to the proxy server?

Comment: Not a programming question - try http://apple.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: Thanks, for info! Will do